# Sendmail local domain relay

Tags: email, dns, localhost, sendmail, relay

Sendmail on webserver.mydomain.com is sending all emails properly except email addressed to anyone@mydomain.com.

mydomain.com's mail is not handled locally and mx records are configured to point to the appropriate mailserver.  But mail sent from sendmail seems to be relayed off the local server instead of the mailserver where the mx records point.

I removed mydomain.com from /etc/mail/local-host-names and restarted sendmail but to no avail. The mail log shows sendmail connecting to the local relay 127.0.0.1 and returning a "User unknown" message.

Comment: For the record, I never solved this but switched to postfix as my MTA and have had no such problem with since.  I'm still interested in a solution using sendmail.

Comment: Is `mydomain.com` on lists of local email domains provided by the commands below? `echo '$=w' | sendmail -bt` , `echo '$=w' | sendmail -bt -O DontProbeInterfaces=Trues` Is it "this host email name"? `echo '$j' | sendmail -bt`

Comment: both of those commands return the error `sendmail: fatal: unsupported: -bt`

Comment: Could you name MTA package you use? [ Exim/postfix/...]  It does not to be sendmail. The other packages "provide sendmail look alike" to allow email sending using sendmail command.

Comment: yes as i said in the first comment i switched to postfix once i couldn't get sendmail to work.